# No idea how to group adjacent objects based on value

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, grouping

I have a network of 500+ objects (each with a value) connected in a specific way, I want a way to organise them into "x" groups so that the sum of each group is as similar as possible and that no groups are made with objects that don't "connect". I don't care how many points are in each group. I don't know if I will need to use an AI, algorithm or whatever. I have tried searching on this topic but I can't find anything relating to my issue (maybe because I do not know the jargon). I have little experience in coding but am happy to learn anything although at the moment I have no idea where to start.

[An example of what I mean by a network of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIhlX.png)

Thanks in advance, any pointers in the right direction are welcomed.

Comment: You'll need to share a bit more code for someone to be able to provide a solution but you should be able to use a graph algorithm to do this.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the graph properties? E.g., min-max neighbors a node can have? min-max node value? That the overall network is connected? Min-max value of x? Tolerance around 'similar' (e.g., is close-to-optimal good enough)? Is the network 'planar' (i.e. can be drawn without edges crossing one another)?

Comment: @Dave A node can have up to 12 neighbours, no min or max on node values, the overall network is connected, x can be anywhere from 1 to roughly 75% of the number of nodes, I am trying to find the best solution so the standard deviation is as low as possible for the groups and the network is planar. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HenryTseng Thanks, I'll check that out